# Facebook Firebase Cloud Messaging - not working

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

1. API key from FCM to Facebook added
2. Send-to-sync work ok https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#checkAPIkey

But from FB console "Push Campaign Setup Verification" to valid "YOUR DEVICE TOKEN" - not working

Error:

> The sender account used to send a message couldn't be authenticated. It's probably due to invalid project number sent as key, or the key is valid but with FCM service disabled, or our servers are not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.

What could be causing thos? Are there any logs I can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All start works after some time